# count a range of elements with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
np.unique([1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1], return_counts=True)
```

returns

```
(array([0, 1, 3]), array([1, 3, 2]))
```

which excludes missing elements, in this case, `2`.

Is there an easy and efficient way to get all counts, for example:

```
count(ar=[1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1], from=0, to=4) # returns [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), passing it a `minlength` of the maximum value in the array plus 1:

```py
ar = np.array([1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1])
np.bincount(ar, minlength=np.amax(ar)+1)
# array([1, 3, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.add.at`:

```
ar = np.array([1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1])
count = np.zeros(np.amax(ar)+1)
np.add.at(count, ar, 1)
```

Output in `count`:

```
array([1., 3., 0., 2.])
```

But using `np.bincount` will be much faster